# slug при обновлении сохраняется как none?

Tags: python-3.x, django

у меня есть класс update для обновления поста/тега , при обновлении тега все обновляется ,а когда пытаюсь пост обновить слаг сохраняется в бд как пустое поле , подскажите в чем ошибка?

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.posts_list, name='posts_list'),
    path('post/create/', views.PostCreate.as_view(), name='post_create_url'),
    path('post/<str:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail_url'),
    path('post/<str:slug>/update/', views.PostUpdate.as_view(), name='post_update_url'),
    path('tags/', views.tags_list, name='tags_list'),
    path('tags/create/', views.TagCreate.as_view(), name='tag_create_url'),
    path('tags/<str:slug>/', views.TagDetail.as_view(), name='tags_detail'),
    path('tags/<str:slug>/update/', views.TagUpdate.as_view(), name='tag_update_url'),
]
```

models.py

```
def gen_slug(s):
    new_slug = slugify(s, allow_unicode=True)
    return new_slug + '-' + str(int(time()))


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True, related_name='posts')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_updated_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_update_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = gen_slug(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:tags_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_updated_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:tag_update_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
class PostUpdate(ObjectUpdateMixin, View):
    model = Post
    model_form = PostForm
    template = 'blog/post_update.html'

class TagUpdate(ObjectUpdateMixin, View):
    model = Tag
    model_form = TagForm
    template = 'blog/tag_update.html'
```

utils.py

```
class ObjectUpdateMixin:
    model = None
    model_form = None
    template = None

    def get(self, request, slug):
        obj = self.model.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
        form = self.model_form(instance=obj)
        return render(request, self.template, {'form': form, self.model.__name__.lower(): obj})

    def post(self, request, slug):
        obj = self.model.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
        form = self.model_form(request.POST, instance=obj)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_obj = form.save()
            return redirect(new_obj)
        return render(request, self.template, {'form': form, self.model.__name__.lower(): obj})
```

templates

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} Post Edit "{{post.title}}" - {{ block.super }} {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="{{post.get_updated_url}}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="form-group">
                {% if field.errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        {{ field.errors }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
                {{ field.label }}
                {{ field }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Post</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `save` измените на:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = gen_slug(self.title)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```